# Absolute import error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my project structure:

```
/project_dir
  /src
    __init__.py
    index.py
    /handler
      __init__.py
      base_handler.py
```

in `index.py` I import `base_handler.BaseHandler` like this:

```
from src.handler.base_handler import BaseHandler
```

and an error occurs:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

The strange thing is, when I move `index.py` out of `src` folder, this error will disappear:

```
/project_dir
  index.py
  /src
    __init__.py
    /handler
      __init__.py
      base_handler.py
```

Now in `index.py` I can import `BaseHandler` like this:

```
from src.handler.base_handler import BaseHandler
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: Why is that strange? If you move the index file out of the source directory, then there *is* a module `src` for it to import from.

Comment: so I can't import the module itself when In this source directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `index.py` if you import `BaseHandler` like this it'll work:

`from handler.base_handler import BaseHandler`

Comment: yeah, I know, but pycharm automatically generate import like this `from src.handler.base_handler import BaseHandler`

Comment: So to have `from src.handler.base_handler import BaseHandler` to work you have to add the full path to your project to `sys.path` like this: `sys.path.insert(0, </path/to/project_dir/>)`. This way you'll be able to import from `src`. I'm not sure how pycharm handles this, but it looks like it's wrong in this case. You simply want to import something from the `handler` package which is on the same level as your `index` module so `from handler.base_handler import BaseHandler` is the full path to `BaseHandler` as far as `index` is concerned

Comment: Also, if this answer was useful to you, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark. This indicates to the community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this! Thanks!